# How to control the gradient on a shape?

Tags: android, background, textview, gradient, shapes

I have a screen with a label on top. This label is done with a TextView.
As a background I'd like to have a vertical gradient, starting with color1, changing to color2 and back to color1.
At the moment I have:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <stroke android:width="1px" android:color="#000000" /> 
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:centerColor="#FF8800"
        android:endColor="#FFFFFFFF" 
        android:type="linear"
        android:angle="270" 
/>
    <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
</shape>
```

My problem is that the centerColor line is too thin. I want it to ocupy all the letters space.
I can't find any way to make the gradient to be faster.
I've already tried to use a layout-list but with no success.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much more different track to follow but have you considered working with 9-patch image files? This will allow you to stretch the parts of the gradient that you wish to and make the centre line as big as needed by segmenting up the background properly.

Here are some great tutorials I have used to learn about them:
[draw 9 patch tutorial](http://www.android10.org/index.php/articlesother/279-draw-9-patch-tutorial)

And from Google's own Android mouth:
[Android 9 patch](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html)
[All Drawable resources for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html)

Comment: I've been looking at this 9patch thing but I can't get the hang of it.
Is it really not possible to do with gradients?

Comment: It works with vertical or horizontal gradients but not so well with oblique ones I think. Can you explain more about where you get stuck when learning about 9patches?

Comment: I can't seem to expand it correctly. I select the center line but it is expanded over the downside of the picture. Meaning I loose the lower gradient.

Comment: Some more info: 
Original file (print screen from eclipse): https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/bg.png
Changes on 9patch: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/9patch.png
Result on eclipse: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/layout.png

Comment: your black markers aren't done correctly. make sure it is only 1 px wide and isn't anti-aliased (should be a button to turn that off in the brush. Also there should be padding around the button that is only 1px clear also without anti-aliasing. it looks like your button goes right to the edge. so.. for a 9patch button that is 32x32px you would create your button and then add 1px on each side so the actual dimensions of the image would be 34x34 in total. The app will automatically remove that border and follow the black markers you've created.

Comment: Ok, slowlly I seem to get it.
Original button: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/bg_button.png
9patch button: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/bg_button.9.png
Result on eclipse: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3501880/bg_buttonlayout.png

As you can see, on eclipse the button is already properly expanded. On the down side, the text is half-cut. Plus, when I try to deploy it to an Android device I get an error:
01-08 17:30:40.935: E/AndroidRuntime(10087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo
And a ClassNotFoundException inside it.

Comment: The text being cut can be solved by changing the height from 48dp to 54dp (probably I need to adjust something).
But the Exception is bugging me...

Comment: The exception was a stupid thing on my AndroidManifest. I changed some paths but forgot to change the manifest. It's now working. Thanks. :)